# QT Choose NDK version Qmake

Tags: android, qt

How do I force choose a specific NDK version for QMake? (21.1.6352462 instead of 21.3.6528147)
The error I get:

> :-1: warning: "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang" is used by qmake, but "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.1.6352462\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe" is configured in the kit.
> Please update your kit (Huawei) or choose a mkspec for qmake that matches your target environment better.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can choose your NDK in QtCreator' menu : Tools/Options/Devices
Android tab, "Android NDK list"